# Api Token is missing in laravel 4.2 api

Tags: laravel, http-headers, access-token

I am solving issue in  API of laravel 4.2 application.
I downloaded project and setup in local.
I signup using given email and password and it gives successfully logged in and throw `api_token` which is stored in database. Now if I use that API token in header it throws error:

> {"status":false,"message":"Api Token is missing","code":"404"}

because it doesn't get `api_token` which is sent putting in header.
If I try to die and dump that header it gives null.

It works fine in online server and recieves `api_token`, and everything works fine but if I try to work on same file in local it gives error.
Please help me.

Header:

```
Accept : Application/json
api_token: ****************
```

it throws `api_token` as null if we try to catch it.
The actual problem it throws is:

> {"status":false,"message":"Api Token is missing","code":"404"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `-`(dash) instead of `_`(underscore) in the header name as:

```
api-token: ****************
```

And get it in laravel as:

```
request()->header('api-token');
```

Comment: I noticed that it is not working actually, it s just disabling the api_token portion

Comment: It's a good practice to use `-` in your header names. I would recommend you to change it in the app.